# can we install xcode_3.2.5_and_ios_sdk_4.2_final on Lion

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios4

Hello I have Lion in my mac airbook, I want to install xcode_3.2.5 on that, I installed it but it is unable to install.

Comment: What do you mean by 'you installed it but it is unable to install.'

Comment: He probably means "It installs half the files. That means the installation went wrong somewhere though it says Succesfully Installed". I faced the similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

Mount xcode325.dmg. Open terminal and type following commands:

```
export COMMAND_LINE_INSTALL=1    
open "/Volumes/Xcode and iOS SDK/Xcode and iOS SDK.mpkg"
```

It should install successfully then.

Answer (score 0):

check it your xcode installation is for what version lion snow leopard.
As per knowledge in lion OS you have to direct install xcode from Apple APP STORE.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install it from Snow Leopard, but it will then run on Lion. So, for example, boot from an external Snow Leopard disc and run the installer from there.

Comment: I got the solution,
If we run following commands on terminal then we can install Xcode 3.2.5

Commands: 
export COMMAND_LINE_INSTALL=1
open "/Volumes/Xcode and iOS SDK/Xcode and iOS SDK.mpkg"